# Two returning string methods call one other method

Tags: c#, .net

I have 2 methods that almost do the same! just a string text is changed. One method returns "hello" and the other returns "goodbye" to the same URL.

how do i refactorise the methods so i dont have to use the same url twice?
thinking of doing 2 seperate methods witch returns the different strings and then calls the url method

```
public void Init()
{
    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("Generate", () => Generate(), Cron.Weekly(DayOfWeek.Monday, 10, 00));
    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("Generate M", () => GenerateGoodBye(), Cron.Weekly(DayOfWeek.Monday, 12, 00));
}

public async Task Generate()
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    await httplClient.PostAsync(new Uri("theURL"), new StringContent("hello");
}

public async Task GenerateGoodBye()
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    await httplClient.PostAsync(new Uri("theURL"), new StringContent("goodbye");
}
```

is it possible to make a method so i just need 1 url method who takes Generate and GenerateGoodBye?

Comment: `public async Task GenerateContent(string content) {...new StringContent(content)}` then `public async Task Generate() => GenerateContent("hello");`

Answer (score 4):

Add param to method and call it with message what you want ot send.

```
string someLongMessage = "...";

public void Init()
{
    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("Generate", () => Generate(someLongMessage), Cron.Weekly(DayOfWeek.Monday, 10, 00));
    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("Generate M", () => Generate("Goodbye"), Cron.Weekly(DayOfWeek.Monday, 12, 00));
}

public async Task Generate(string message)
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    await httplClient.PostAsync(new Uri("theURL"), new StringContent(message);
}
```

Comment: Hello and GoodBýe where just examples, the text would be much longer is it able to do it without typing in genereate("hello"), cron.Weekly...

because of typing there would make it very hard to understand

Comment: @Andreas I edited my answer with call with other variable. You can declare some string variable and send it to method.

Comment: If you only have 2 possible text string values as outputs, the added param does not need to be a string, it could be a bool type. Your method could then output one string value for bool=0 and another for bool=1.

Comment: @JohnH in my opinion your solution is more ugly and not clean. More flexible is param as string. So without any change you can add another message text.